# Estruturar projeto React

Tags: javascript, react, react-native

Galera,

Criei um projeto react-native e quero estruturar iternamente com pastas, por exemplo criar a pasta screens para criar o componentes la.

A duvida de iniciante. Sempre que executo o projeto ele é redirecionado para o index.android.js

Nesse caso se eu criar uma ./screens/index.js, eu preciso redirecionar no index.android.js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correto.

Ambas plataformas sempre irão primeiramente executar os arquivos `index.ios.js` ou `index.android.js`. Você pode usar isso ao seu favor e fazer customizações específicas para cada plataforma usando esses arquivos.

Idealmente você irá dar `require` em uma outra janela (dentro de  `./screens`, por exemplo) dentro desses arquivos `index` e irá abri-las.